# Override admin_menu.py file in django admin panel for sidebar customization

Tags: django, django-admin-tools

There is a file called admin_menu.py in django_adminlte_theme>templatetags.

This file is used for customization of sidebar of django admin panel i.e. dropdowns menus are their order
Everything is set except the main thing i.e. override this, right now I am doing this by overriding i the base file which came on the installation and we cannot upload this with other files on server.

I have tried a few things like changing the templates directory in settings.py, adding site-packages or django-adminlte-theme folder in my project directory

Is their anyway of doing this???
Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I got my required answer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/). It has described everything I want to know